# Should we use non-standard ports for backend service of my app?

Tags: web-services, rest, mobile

We are developing an mobile app for my company, which need to connect in a https webservice. My company provide us a external ip and a specific non-standard (that is, NOT 443) port that we are supposed to use to external connections. The specific host that we are supposed to use already has another service in 443 port.

My question is, would be better use a standard port, if possible? The user will never need to type the host and port, is a hidden configuration, but i am worry if in some networks (like public wi-fi) could have firewalls blocking non-standard ports. Is this common? Should I ask to use to use the standard port for better connectivity?

Comment: `but i am worry if in some networks (like public wi-fi) could have firewalls blocking non-standard ports. Is this common? `  yes, blocking outbound ports is very common. Company networks do this, even some countries are blocking outbound port ranges.

Comment: To overcome your occupied service on the `443` port, you can use host header to switch between them. Although the implementation is a typical detail of the service which you use to host the service. Can be IIS, appache, etc.